# style odd and even nodes near coords differently

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I'm using this style definition in the preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  base/.style={
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
  }
}

\pgfplotsset{
  random/.style={
    ybar=3pt,
    bar width=10pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.08,
    tick label style={font=\small},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(-0.06,0.5)},rotate=90},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    every axis legend/.append style={font=\small},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1, style={font=\small}},
    legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.4cm}}
  }
}
```

to create the following tikzpicture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12.6cm,
      base,
      random,
      ylabel={\%},
      symbolic x coords={Google,Facebook,YouTube,Yahoo,Baidu,Wikipedia,QQ,Twitter,Taobao,Amazon},
      x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {
      (Google,1.33)
      (Facebook,1.83)
      (YouTube,1.06)
      (Yahoo,1.38)
      (Baidu,0)
      (Wikipedia,3.13)
      (QQ,0)
      (Twitter,1.47)
      (Taobao,1.00)
      (Amazon,1.09)
    };
    \addplot coordinates {
      (Google,1.59)
      (Facebook,2.16)
      (YouTube,2.76)
      (Yahoo,1.61)
      (Baidu,0)
      (Wikipedia,3.13)
      (QQ,0)
      (Twitter,2.41)
      (Taobao,3.19)
      (Amazon,1.33)
    };
    \legend{Separated, Cascaded}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and as you can see for the wikipedia entry, the node numbers overlap:

[image: output image]

the font size is already small, so i would like not to deacrease it.

how can I style differently the odd and even columns' nodes?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would shift the nodes on blue columns slightly to the left, and nodes on the red columns slightly to the right by using the `every node near coord/.append style={xshift=<dim>}` key together with the `\addplot+` command (instead of `\addplot`).

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  base/.style={
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
  }
}

\pgfplotsset{
  random/.style={
    ybar=3pt,
    bar width=10pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.08,
    tick label style={font=\small},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(-0.06,0.5)},rotate=90},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    every axis legend/.append style={font=\small},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1, style={font=\small}},
    legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.4cm}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=12.6cm,
      base,
      random,
      ylabel={\%},
      symbolic x coords={Google,Facebook,YouTube,Yahoo,Baidu,Wikipedia,QQ,Twitter,Taobao,Amazon},
      x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east}
    ]
    \addplot+[every node near coord/.append style={xshift=-0.75pt}] coordinates {
      (Google,1.33)
      (Facebook,1.83)
      (YouTube,1.06)
      (Yahoo,1.38)
      (Baidu,0)
      (Wikipedia,3.13)
      (QQ,0)
      (Twitter,1.47)
      (Taobao,1.00)
      (Amazon,1.09)
    };
    \addplot+[every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0.75pt}] coordinates {
      (Google,1.59)
      (Facebook,2.16)
      (YouTube,2.76)
      (Yahoo,1.61)
      (Baidu,0)
      (Wikipedia,3.13)
      (QQ,0)
      (Twitter,2.41)
      (Taobao,3.19)
      (Amazon,1.33)
    };
    \legend{Separated, Cascaded}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]